# sql relational divide selecting all entries with a column that have all values in a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sqlite, relational-division

I have a table like this:

```
fields1 | field2
----------------
1_______| a_____
1_______| b_____
1_______| c_____
2_______| a_____
2_______| c_____
```

and a list of field2 [a,b,c].

I need preferable 1 SQL query that select all field1 entries with the follow conditions:

- the list include all fields2  ex: 1 (a,b,c), OR
- all fields2 are included in the list ex: 2 (a,c)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want a list of all field1 that have no entry other then those mentioned in the list? So output would be two rows: the values 1 and 2? But if there was an entry 2|d, the output would only be one row with the value 1, because 2 had then an entry not in the list [a,b,c]?

Comment: And why do you tag three different DBMS plus an OR mapper? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` clause with `CASE WHEN`:

> the list include all fields2 ex: 1 (a,b,c)

`SQL Server`:

```
SELECT LEFT(fields1,1) AS result
FROM #tab
GROUP BY LEFT(fields1,1)
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN field2 LIKE 'a%' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN field2 LIKE 'b%' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN field2 LIKE 'c%' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN field2 LIKE '[^abc]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0; 
   -- add last condition only if 'a....|b....|c....` are allowed
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/405986)**</kbd>

> all fields2 are included in the list ex: 2 (a,c)

```
SELECT LEFT(fields1,1) AS result
FROM #tab
GROUP BY LEFT(fields1,1)
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN field2 LIKE 'a%' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN field2 LIKE 'c%' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN field2 LIKE '[^ac]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
   -- add last condition only if 'a...|c...' are allowed
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/406001)**</kbd>

Another way is to use `COUNT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT LEFT(fields1,1) AS result
FROM #tab
WHERE LEFT(field2, 1) IN ('a','b','c')
GROUP BY LEFT(fields1,1)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(field2, 1)) = 3
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN LEFT(field2, 1) NOT IN ('a','b','c') THEN 1 END) = 0
   -- add last condition only if 'a....|b....|c....` are allowed
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo3`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/406005)**</kbd>